# wordpress editor deletes the <tr><td>

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

I want to arrange content in my page with tables, but when I write the code, and switch back to visual mode then back again to text mode all the

```
 <tr> and <td>
```

are missing, there is a way to keep this code?

Thank you

Comment: would be great to see some code/examples...

Comment: It is a security thing that wordpress does... You can't stop it... The only way to keep it is to save it in the "text" editor and not switch...

Answer (score 3):

either you disable the visual editor or use table creating plugin in wordpress for this, wordpress stripping html tags when swich to visual editor.

Comment: ok, and how the table creating plugins manage to not strip the code, if they can, then must exist a code that prevents this without installing a plugin

Comment: I do not really know php, but may be an idea a script that search and replase for ex: --mytr-- with <tr> ???

Comment: I tried this:    <?php echo str_replace("mytr","<tr>", the_content();); ?>    but it`s not working any idea?

Comment: php does not work in editor, if you really want to work this out like plugin do .. try searching for appropriate action and filter

Answer (score 0):

keep your content in text & don't switch to html before saving that content, else download the plugin for that is the simple solution.